# Sed replace string within quotes

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace string within quotes in a file! Here is an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Manager pathname="" />
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"   maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/custom" password="CHANGEIT" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/database" username="MyUser"/>
</Context>
```

This command works for several 'fields' but it doesn't work with username because of / .

```
# It's OK
sed 's/\(.*password=\)[^ ]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml

# It's NOK
sed 's/\(.*username=\)[^ ]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml
```

How can I do that please ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the command

```
sed 's/\(.*username=\)[^ ]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml
```

into

```
sed 's/\(.*username=\)[^ \/]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml
```

because `[^ ]` means: Every character except a `blank`. `[^ \/]` means: Every character except a `blank` and/or `/`.

Comment: Thanks... but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: What do you get, if you run my adjusted command on the text in your initial question?

Comment: I've got this :
[root@mymachine ~]# sed 's/\(.*username=\)[^ \/]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Manager pathname="" />
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"   maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/custom" password="CHANGEIT" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/database" username="MyUser"/>
</Context>  No changes made

Comment: Why are you calling `sed` with `(.*username=)` instead of `\(.*username=\)` and `( .*)` instead of `\( .*\)` ? Look here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-10

Comment: Look at your command: `sed 's/(.*username=)[^ \/]*( .*)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml`. Then look at my comment.

Comment: Sorry.. but i have the same results :    
   `# sed 's/\(.*username=\)[^ \/]*\( .*\)/\1"NEW_VALUE"\2/' ROOT.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context>
    <Manager pathname="" />
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/lsdf" password="ACHANGER" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/MyDatabase" username="MyUser"/>
    </Context>`

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

`sed 's/\( username="\)[^"]*/\1NEW_VALUE/' ROOT.xml`

It will get any pattern with a *space* + **username** + *double quotation* until the next *double quotation* and change for the first part and the new value.